# Unable todo any action in child window, i'm using acttime application

Tags: selenium

Unable todo any action in child window, i'm using acttime application.

Trying to create new user.

Tried with javascript and sendkeys and as well as keboard events also.

It would be great if i get solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you tried switching your driver to child window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi please check the below code that i used for my own purpose. In the code i tried to handled the windows (Parent and child windows). Use the same format of the code it can help you. Cheers.

Code:

```
//Clicking on Add symbol
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/table[4]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/a/img")).click();

Thread.sleep(3000L);

driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='basicTab']/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/input")).sendKeys("Pro2");

Thread.sleep(3000L);
String HandleFirst = driver.getWindowHandle();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='basicTab']/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[8]/td[2]/img")).click();

//Swithing the window
for(String handle : driver.getWindowHandles())
{
    driver.switchTo().window(handle);
}

//Perform operation in new window

WebElement element1=driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/select"));
Select se1=new Select(element1);
se1.selectByIndex(1);
Thread.sleep(3000L);

driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]/input")).click();

driver.close();

//Switching to original window

driver.switchTo().window(HandleFirst);

driver.quit();

}
```

Comment: Hi Sandeep, thanks for helping, it's working fine now. Earlier also i switched to child window.

Comment: Now script is running succesfully but in console showing error as org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: no such session

Comment: @Magisch Hi no need to edit the code he understood what i said.

Comment: @sandeepkumar I just formatted some code you forgot to format properly as code.

Comment: Thanks for the edit :)